# jQuery ajax call to ASP.NET calling wrong method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this ajax call here:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/action/deleteData?issueID=16",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert('Failed, somthing went wrong, please try again!');
                    }
                });
```

which is trying to call this method

```
    public string deleteData(string issueID)
    {
        return "aaa";
    }
```

however, this is calling the wrong method, its calling a method with no parameters. Why is it doing this and how can I fix this?

The action is correct or otherwise it wouldn't be going into the other method.

When I manually try to call this method with the URL, its returns the data from the wrong method. I dont get it.

Comment: is the asp.net web forms?  or MVC?

Comment: This is asp.net MVC

Comment: "its returns the data from the wrong method" what method is being called/returning data?  there may be an issue with MVC not reading the route correctly

Comment: What happens if you change your action signature to accept an int parameter instead of string? Otherwise, I think we may need to see your route definitions/setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `[ActionName("deleteData")]` to your WEB API action and it will work.I justed tested on my side and it's working perfectly.Below is my `ApiController`:

```
public class actionController : ApiController
{
    public string deleteData()
    {
        return "deleteData";
    }

    public string doSomething()
    {
        return "doSomething";
    }

    [ActionName("deleteData")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string deleteData(string issueID)
    {
        return "aaa";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the way you pass your parameter is correct. I tend to always use the data property of the ajax call to pass in my parameter.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/action/deleteData",
                data: ({ issueID: 16 }),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert('Failed, somthing went wrong, please try again!');
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope that did nothing

Comment: Hum I wonder i wonder if it's because you are using an api. Have you tried the following: url: "/api/action/deleteData/16"

Comment: apis, webservices and regular mvc methods take parameters differently